# Determine if connect-msolservice has already been successfully called

Tags: powershell, office365

I am writing an Office 365 assistance tool in PowerShell and have what I think is a simple question I can't find the answer to. How can I tell if a connection as created by `Connect-MsolService` is present and active? There must be some way to know because the other cmdlets can check, I just don't know what that way is and I'm not having luck finding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Connect-MsolService` return an object once connected, and as far as I can see doesn't add new variables. Maybe you can determine that by running one of the module commands and base it on the execution result of the command:

```
Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($?)
{
    "connected"
}
else
{
    "disconnected"
}
```

Comment: hmm that seems a bit sloppy... there must be something the Microsoft cmdlets are doing to know to throw the error but it might be internal offlimits stuff?

Comment: I don't know, that workaround is all I can offer at the moment.

Comment: ok, let's let this sit for a little while and see if someone comes up with something cleaner. If not I'll accept this as it is a way to do it.

Comment: Fair enough @MikeBaz, digging in :)

Comment: For what it's worth, the module is writing logs here: $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Office365\Powershell

Comment: Bit of a tweak that makes it easier to reuse. A zero means no connection. Useful for a logging schema where 1 or 0 are the standard result output.
$checkConnection = Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$checkConnection.Count

Comment: For some reason, this still returns that it is connected even if the credentials were wrong during the connection attempt. I found this out while testing my script and accidentally put in the wrong credentials. The next time I ran it, it did not attempt to reconnect because this `Get-MsolDomain` returned what it usually returns when I'm successfully authenticated.

Answer (score 8):

This was my solution.

```
try
{
    Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction Stop > $null
}
catch 
{
    if ($cred -eq $null) {$cred = Get-Credential $O365Adminuser}
    Write-Output "Connecting to Office 365..."
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  This feels like a basic variant of the same pattern - but it reads a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this is how I did this:

```
# Only run if not already connected
if(-not (Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
    $O365Cred = Get-Credential -Message "Please provide credentials for Microsoft Online"

    $O365Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $O365Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -ErrorAction Stop
    Connect-MsolService –Credential $O365Cred

    Import-PSSession $O365Session | Out-Null
}
```

If the `Connect-MsolService` line comes before the `$O365Session =` line, then inputting incorrect credentials will lead to a false positive on your next run (it will think you're connected, even though you're not because the credentials were wrong.) Doing it this way prevents that little hiccup from happening.

Also notice the `-ErrorAction Stop` at the end of the `$O365Session = New-PSSession` line. This prevents it from attempting the `Connect-MsolService` line with incorrect credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$?) { "You're not connected to MSOnline."; Connect-MsolService }

Here is a check I run first to make sure the module is installed:

if ( ! (Get-InstalledModule -Name MSOnline -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{ Install-Module MSOnline -Force }

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is `get-pssession`and that will let you know if you are connected to msol services based on the configuration name.  If you want to automate a connection process you can set up an if else loop to check the configuration name and the state.  Let me know if you would like an example of this, I have this set up on a web app I built to query user information on Office 365 and display it on a web page.

Comment: I just tried this - connected with Connect-MsolService, then Get-PSSession. Nothing comes back. Are you thinking of the Exchange Online portion, where you use an explicit PS session you create?

Comment: Yeah maybe I am confused what you are trying to do.  What is your end game here, what type of tool are you trying to create, that would help me give you the answer you are looking for

Comment: Without going into a huge amount of detail, the tool is configuring Office 365 domains and federation. I don't want to bother asking for credentials to connect if there is a working connection already. Connections outlive even the script lifetime so it's something to check even on a new instance of the tool. I don't want to ask for credentials and call Connect-MsolService unless I have to.

Answer (score -2):

`Connect-MsolService` imports a module into powershell called MSOnline, so just need to check if the module is present:

```
Get-Module -Name MSOnline
```

Comment: You have that backwards - the module being imported makes the command available, not the other way around.