# Determin if connection to office365 is vaild, if not connect, then do something

Tags: office365, azure-powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that executes the Get-DistributionGroup cmdlet.  But I want to make sure I have a vaild Office 365 Connection first, if not create connection. Then run cmdlet.

The problem is I also want to make sure the connection succeeds before trying to run the cmdlet. I've used [Determine if connect-msolservice has already been successfully called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977477/determine-if-connect-msolservice-has-already-been-successfully-called) to get what I have.  But it's not working.

Basically what I want to do is:

1. Check for connection
2. If connection valid, run command.
3. If not Valid, attempt to connect.
4. If connection Fails, abort.
5. else run command

What I have so far is...

```
param([string]$GroupName)
$Username = "$GroupName@mydomain.com"
<#
Write-Host "Searching for any Groups that contain '" -NoNewLine
Write-Host "$Username" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor yellow
Write-Host "'"
#>
try
{
    Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction Stop > $null
}
catch 
{
    Write-Output "Connecting to Office 365..."
    if ($cred -eq $null) {$cred = Get-Credential $O365Adminuser}
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred   
}

try
{
    Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction Stop > $null
    Get-DistributionGroup | where { (Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Name | foreach {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}) -contains "$Username"}
}
catch 
{
    throw "Error, connection Failed"
}
```

The output is:
[image: Powershell Output]

Comment: Don't you have the user login/authenticate as an O365 admin at the beginning of your script?

Comment: @TylerH I was trying to do that in the catch.  The idea was you could run the script multiple times, and not have to provide Cred's and create a session every time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've figured out what was going on.

1. I was mixing powershell session configurations.

   - **Get-MsolDomain** is for Azure Active Directory.
   - Where **Get-DistributionGroup** was from Office365/Exchange Online
2. It was working as intended.  The issue was the cmdlet **Get-DistributionGroup** is part of the Exchange/office365 online config, and thus was falling to the catch due to the cmdlet not found, not because the session failed to create.

So to fix, I had to do the following:

1. Move the **Get-DistribitonGroup** outside the catch.
2. Switch the **Get-MsolDomain** to **Get-PSSession**

I also added some writes to the screen (for diagnostics) and additional error checking to make sure the Credentials were supplied.

Here is the final Script:

```
param([string]$GroupName)
$Username = "$GroupName@mydomain.com"

Write-Host "Searching for any Groups that contain '" -NoNewLine
Write-Host "$Username" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor yellow
Write-Host "'"


Get-PSSession | Where { $_.ConfigurationName -eq "Microsoft.Exchange" }

if (!(Get-PSSession | Where { $_.ConfigurationName -eq "Microsoft.Exchange" })) 
{ 
    Write-Output "Creating Credentials for Office 365..."
    if ($UserCredential -eq $null) 
    {
        try
        {
            $UserCredential = Get-Credential $O365Adminuser
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "Credentials not provided, exiting..." -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor black
            exit
        }
    }
    Write-Output "Creating Session for Office 365..."
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Write-Output "Connecting to Office 365..."
    try
    {
        Import-PSSession $Session -ErrorAction Stop 
    }
    catch
    {
        throw "Error, connection Failed"
    }
}
    Write-Output "Seaching Office 365..."

Get-DistributionGroup | where { (Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Name | foreach {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}) -contains "$Username"}
```